# Selecting a particular output value in SAS proc univariate

Tags: statistics, sas

I'm interested in calculating the skewness of a dataset in SAS. Using the `proc univariate` statement I can get summary statistics, thus the skewness. Is it possible to get just the value of the skewness as output? I also need that value to do some calculations in the next lines, therefore I'll need a way to acces just that value, not all the summary statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of what's available with `ods trace`.

```
ods trace on;
proc univariate data=sashelp.class;
  var age;
run;
ods trace off;
```

Moments is the table that contains skewness; you can use KEEP statements and/or WHERE statements to filter to just that value.

```
ods output moments=class_moments;
proc univariate data=sashelp.class;
  var age;
run;
ods output close;
```

And then the keep statements particular to skewness:

```
ods output moments=class_moments(keep=varname cValue1 label1 where=(label1='Skewness'));
proc univariate data=sashelp.class;
  var age;
run;
ods output close;
```

Comment: Follow-up on my question: how can I refer to the value of the skewness in order to do some calculations involving it? Furthermore, since I want to write in the log the value of the skewness, I run `%put class_moments` but it writes in the log just the text string "class_moments" not the value in it. How can I do that?

Comment: The point of `ods output` is to put the value of skewness into a dataset - if you run my sample code at the end you will have `class_moments` dataset that contains the value for skewness in `cValue1` (which you can then rename if you want).

Comment: Okay, but what if I want to calculate, let's say, 2*skewness? How can I use the value in `cValue1`?

Comment: I think you need to read a basic primer on the SAS language if you're asking that.  The dataset is the basic data element in SAS.